# How can " A smell leapt out so horrid that it seemed to colour the air " be correct?

Tags: grammar, word-order

> A smell leapt out so horrid that it seemed to colour the air.

I thought this sentence should be "A smell so horrid leapt out that it seemed to colour the air." Which one is right?

Comment: I disagree with the re-write. Your version is ungrammatical. Could you edit your question to explain your reasoning? Thanks.

Comment: I thought "smell so horrid" was the result of whiz-deletion that was connected with the so~that phrase.

Comment: It looks like a poorly written mixed metaphor. Horror and color aren't generally used together, even in figurative expressions.

Comment: Yeah, I agree -- it should be "color", not "colour".  But otherwise the original is just fine and sounds like the work of a skilled and talented writer.

Comment: @sooeithdk It is whiz-deletion, but the relative clause is not just “(which was) so horrid”, but “(which was) so horrid that it seemed to colour the air”. So if you want to move the verb into its unmarked position, that's after the entire relative clause: “A smell so horrid that it seemed to colour the air leapt out”. That's grammatical, but clumsy because the actual subject (_smell_) is so far removed from its verb. That's why in the original, the relative clause has been moved down after the verb instead. That's grammatical as well, though it does make the sentence more formal-sounding.

Comment: So only the first one is correct?

Comment: Yes. Try whiz-undeleting your rewrite: “A smell which was so horrible leapt out that it seemed to colour the air”—that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: "Correct" is a tail told by an idiom.

Comment: "A smell streamed out, a smell so horrid that it seemed to colour the air."

Comment: What about "A smell streamed out, so horrid that it seemed to colour the air."

Comment: Hot licks takes a purely American viewpoint in advocating color rather than colour. On this side of the Atlantic I would edit out color and change it to colour.

Comment: My correction of "colour" was, of course, tongue-in-cheek.  The original is very well written.

Comment: The sentence is beyond horrid. Why are we even talking about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*In answer to the question, but also some comments:*

The sentence is entirely grammatical. If you want, you can imagine a comma in it:

> A smell leapt out, so horrid that it seemed to colour the air.

(But the comma holds up the urgency of the leaping stink).

The sentence does *not* contain a mixed metaphor (  *seemed to* makes the image a simile if anything).

*"Horror and color aren't generally used together ..."*. Well, good writers are good because they don't write what is *generally used*; the sentence structure and the image are startling, just as is the smell.

The smell is so horrid that you can almost see it in the air. (And to get even more lit crit about it: look how "colour" gives a sense of the smell's diffusion - there's no shape to it, it just hangs ominously in the air.)

I'm pretty sure this sentence is by Terry Pratchett, a very well known and respected British writer.

Comment: Commas, yes. That part of the sentence strikes me as an interjection and I think it should have one after *horrid* as well. It is the writer's preference to leave them all out. If [*Buffalo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo) doesn't need comas, neither does this.

Comment: Hmm, not sure about the second comma. "The smell was so horrid that it seemed to colour the air" is the unit of meaning (it seemed to colour the air _because_  it was so horrid.)

Answer (score 2):

> - **"A smell leapt out so horrid that it seemed to colour the air."**

Your first sentence is well-written and seems to paint a picture of the situation. 
"Colour" is also correct in BrE spelling.

**"so......that"** - is used in clauses of result, which can be expressed by "so.....that" or "such....that".

Examples:

- The snow fell **so** fast **that** the streets were covered up in a few minutes.
- He spoke for **such** a long time **that** everybody fell asleep.
- He looked **so** furious **that** nobody dared come near him.
- A smell leapt out **so** horrid **that** it seemed to colour the air.

Answer (score 1):

I find your first sentence clear and expressive. I would not change a word of it. Your second version reads as if the leaping out coloured the air, whereas the first says clearly that it is the horrid aspect that colours the air.

Answer (score -5):

"Horrid" is an adjective not an adverb. Therefore, I think the correct sentence should be 
"A horrid smell leapt out that it seemed to color the air. "

Comment: It's being used as an adjective in the original.

Comment: Your answer is good through the word _out_: " "A horrid smell leapt out..." but then it runs into trouble with  _that it_, which doesn't follow from the preceding words. You might put things right in your rendering by deleting the word _it_: "A horrid smell leapt out that seemed to color the air." Or you might move the "that seemed..." phrase next to the word it modifies (_smell_): "A horrid smell that seemed to color the air leapt out." Or you might transpose "leapt out" as "out leapt" and bring it to the front: "Out leapt a horrid smell that seemed to color the air." ...

Comment: ... My own preference, though, would be "Out leapt a smell so horrid that it seemed to color the air."